# Use SSD for web server

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Im building a new server for my company and would like to know which option is better?
using SSD or traditional hard drives with RAID 10?

I prediect that the web server will perform a lot of read/write operations, do SSDs have shorter life span?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically SSDs do have a shorter lifespan, it depends on how much writing you do, in our tests we managed to totally kill some supposed enterprise-class disks in less a week (we were HAMMERING them however). Of course you really don't mention the nature of your application, very often it'll be faster and more reliable to just have more memory to be honest. I'd look at your storage-requirements in relationship to your memory to see if you can cache the most frequently accessed data after that I'd see how many IOPS your disks are doing and base my decision on that.

Answer (score 1):

If your web server performs a lot of random access I/O and disk capacities are not an issue, then SSD is a good option. Keep in mind though, that you should use RAID for SSDs as well to increase fault tolerance. I can't comment on the SSD life span. We have few machines with Intel SSDs for about 1.5 years. So far so good.

Answer (score 1):

Also using SSD as a busy webserver. Been up and running for a year with no problems yet, we're using Intel X25m drives.

I'm also very interested in the lifespan issues but to be honest I've had hard disks last less time.

Its certainly blazingly fast.